# Function not validating

Tags: php, function, validation

I have created a simple `php` page that needs to validate if the amount entered is `greater than 100` or must return an `error`. My function though does not get called when posting and the amount is `less than 100`

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
    <body>

        <?php

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

        $amountErr = "";
        $amount = "";
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (($_POST["amount"]) > 100) {
                $amountErr = "Value must be equal or greater than 100";
            } else {
                $amount = test_input($_POST["amount"]);
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
            <p><span class="error">*required field.</span></p>

            Amount:<input type="text" name="amount"/>
            <span class="error">*<?php echo $amountErr; ?></span>

            <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Karl someone wants some points. Shame when you help these anonymous users and they just take the answer and leave, never to be seen again, well, until their next issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to error if the value is less than 100, and run the function if it's greater or equal to you should use `<` if it's less than 100, it will set the error variable, else, it will run the function. You also don't need $_POST["amount"] in brackets whilst in the if statement, unless of course there's more than one conditional.

Also, on a side note, it helps a lot to indent code so you can read it easier.

```
<?php
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
$amountErr="";
$amount="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST["amount"] < 100) {
        $amountErr = "Value must be equal or greater than 100";
    } else {
        $amount = test_input($_POST["amount"]);
    }
}

?>
```